# fixed выравнивание шапки по центру

Tags: html, css

Как сделать выравнивание блока по центру, если блок `position: fixed;` ?

`margin 0;` - не работает. Ширина фиксированная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для адаптивной верстки -

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">lorem
  </div
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    left: calc(50% - 'половина ширины внутреннего блока'px);
}
```